# Custom stored data for Recurly form submission

Tags: ruby, recurly

I want to add custom fields to my form submission to Recurly, essentially using them as my database. That way, I could avoid creating a user / prodcuct model and just punt to Recurly's service. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recurly doesn't have support for custom data, however if you collect extra information it might be possible to store it in used fields like username, company name, or the account-level address information. Just be aware that the format/usage of those fields are subject to change.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I'll save the info on my end.